# iOS - can't tap UIView during a UIViewAnimation with a scale transform

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have this 'flash' animation which makes the view (with tap recogniser) get bigger and smaller by CGAffineTransformMakeScale and UIViewAnimation. The problem is the user can't tap the button while it's still doing the animation.

How do I fix this? Do I have to run the flash methods asynchronously (or is UIViewAnimation already async).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the block animation method (which you should be) then you can add the option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`.

This will allow taps while the animation is in progress.

You can read the docs here... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

The method is...

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                  delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
             animations:(void (^)(void))animations
             completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

On my iPad atm but there are dress of tutorials about using this method if you're not already. (And if you're not then you should be).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What uiview method allows this?

Comment: oh i was looking at the keyframes method for the options (oops). Thanks btw!

Comment: The animateKeyFrames method also has options. It's pretty much identical but allows you to specify key frames at different points of the animation instead of just the end state. @Dylanthepiguy

Comment: It's just i was looking at the UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions not UIViewAnimationOptions

Comment: Yup. Such a quick fix. Thanks

Comment: Remember to accept if it fixes the problem @Dylanthepiguy :-)

Comment: Oh right. I kept checking up until it said you can answer in 1 min then I forgot.`[self facepalm]`;